# React : How to force the browser to send a specific header for OPTION (preflight)

Tags: javascript, http, browser, reactjs, cors

I'm writing a lovely rest web service that I now plan to use for a specific webapp built with ReactJS.

Of course everything is ready (cors, options, ...) but I face a sad problem: my WS require that every request contains a 'version' header, to avoid facing versioning problem but I have no idea how to tell my browser to add this header when making preflight request.

So first, is it possible? Then, how to achieve that with ReactJS?

Comment: afaik, the browser itself generates the OPTIONS 100% without dev/user input

Answer (score 0):

This is not managed by ReactJs (which deals with your UI), but by the library you choose to make Http-requests to the web-service.

For example, you could use the classical [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()). You could also use the recent [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers), for which you need a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).